# How can join multiple arraylists

Tags: java

I have two different arraylists. In the first, there are vars (title,author,isbn,date,kind). In the second there are (title,author,isbn,date,kind,field) such as Strings. I dont use super class or subclass.Finally i want these arraylists to populate in common jtable
When i run the program with the first arraylist i take this result [1st_arraylist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNYLk.jpg)
When i run the program with the second arraylist i take this result
[2st_arraylist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fogr6.jpg)
When i run the program both of two arraylists i take this result
[both arraylists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIdZb.jpg)
I want to view both arraylists in one jtable
My code

```
public class LiteraryBookList {
        private ArrayList<LiteraryBook> LibookList;

        public LiteraryBookList() {
            LibookList = new ArrayList<LiteraryBook>();
        }

        public void add(LiteraryBook lb) {
            LibookList.add(lb);
        }

        public ArrayList<LiteraryBook> getBooks() {
            return LibookList;
        }

        public void readFromTxt(String filename) {
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new FileReader(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
            BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = "";
            int counter = 0;
            String title = "";
            String author = "";
            String isbn = "";
            String date = "";
            String kind = "";

            try {
                while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                     if (line.isEmpty() || line.contains("1")) {
                        continue;
                     }
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        title = line;
                    } else if (counter == 2) {
                        author = line;
                    } else if (counter == 3) {
                        isbn = line;
                    } else if (counter == 4) {
                        date = line;
                    } else if (counter == 5) {
                        kind = line;
                        LiteraryBook lb = new LiteraryBook(title, author, isbn, date, kind);
                        LibookList.add(lb);
                        counter = 0;

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LiteraryBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        public Object[][] convert2Data() {
            Object[][] data = new Object[LibookList.size()][5];
            for (int i = 0; i < LibookList.size(); i++) {
                data[i][0] = LibookList.get(i).getTitle();
                data[i][1] = LibookList.get(i).getAuthor();
                data[i][2] = LibookList.get(i).getIsbn();
                data[i][3] = LibookList.get(i).getDate();
                data[i][4] = LibookList.get(i).getKind();
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
```

**Also i have..**

```
public class ScientificBookList {

    private ArrayList<ScientificBook> ScibookList;

    public ScientificBookList() {
        ScibookList = new ArrayList<ScientificBook>();
    }

    public void add(ScientificBook sb) {
        ScibookList.add(sb);
    }

    public ArrayList<ScientificBook> getBooks() {
        return ScibookList;
    }

    public void readFromTxt(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        FileReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        String sci_title = "";
        String sci_author = "";
        String sci_isbn = "";
        String sci_date = "";
        String sci_kind = "";
        String scientific_field = "";

        try {
            while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.isEmpty() || line.contains("2")) {
                    continue;
                }

                counter++;
                if (counter == 1) {
                    sci_title = line;
                } else if (counter == 2) {
                    sci_author = line;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    sci_isbn = line;
                } else if (counter == 4) {
                    sci_date = line;
                } else if (counter == 5) {
                    sci_kind = line;
                } else if (counter == 6) {
                    scientific_field = line;

                    ScientificBook sb = new ScientificBook(sci_title, sci_author, sci_isbn, sci_date, sci_kind,scientific_field);
                    ScibookList.add(sb);
                    counter = 0;

                }

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LiteraryBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Object[][] convert2Data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[ScibookList.size()][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < ScibookList.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = ScibookList.get(i).getSci_Title();
            data[i][1] = ScibookList.get(i).getSci_Author();
            data[i][2] = ScibookList.get(i).getSci_Isbn();
            data[i][3] = ScibookList.get(i).getSci_Date();
            data[i][4] = ScibookList.get(i).getSci_Kind();
            data[i][5] = ScibookList.get(i).getScientific_field();

        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

**Finally i have**

```
public class ShowBooks extends JFrame {

    private Object[][] data;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Title", "Author", "Isbn", "Date", "Kind", "Field"};
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private JTable table;

    private LiteraryBookList myList1;
    private ScientificBookList myList2;


    public ShowBooks() {

        setBounds(10, 10, 400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myList1 = new LiteraryBookList();
        myList2 = new ScientificBookList();

        myList1.readFromTxt("test.txt");
        myList2.readFromTxt("test.txt");

        data = myList1.convert2Data();
        data = myList2.convert2Data();

        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 280));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Comment: See the documentation for [`ArrayList#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: It seems that you're looking for a way to merge two raw 2D object arrays.

Comment: yes man..can you help me?

Comment: You need to post what have you tried and the error you are getting.

Comment: ok i update it..

Comment: It seems that you're trying to read the same file and expect to retrieve different data.

Comment: yes..can you help?

Comment: I have already provided an answer, though it may get multiple downvotes.

Comment: Error: local vars referenced from lambda expression must be final or effectively final..i did all vars final but i have the same error

Comment: You may check the update

Comment: may delete something from my code?

Comment: myList1 = new LiteraryBookList();
        myList2 = new ScientificBookList();

        myList1.readFromTxt("test.txt");
        myList2.readFromTxt("test.txt");
        
        data = myList1.convert2Data();
        data = myList2.convert2Data();

Comment: something of above?

Comment: i must read data from file one time..how do this

Comment: You should have asked for clarifications under the answer - I would get notifications then.
Yes, your lines calling to `convert2Data` are not needed

Comment: how can read once time the file...with which var?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a dirty solution somewhat duplicating `convert2Data` methods which should not be called at all:

```
// prepare one large array to contain both types of books
data = new Object[myList1.getBooks().size() + myList2.getBooks().size()][6];

int row = 0;
// fill 2D array with scientific books' data
for (ScientificBook book : myList1.getBooks()) {
    data[row][0] = book.getSci_Title();
    data[row][1] = book.getSci_Author();
    data[row][2] = book.getSci_Isbn();
    data[row][3] = book.getSci_Date();
    data[row][4] = book.getSci_Kind();
    data[row][5] = book.getScientific_field();
    row++;
}

// fill 2D array with literary books' data
for (LiteraryBook book : myList2.getBooks()) {
    data[row][0] = book.getTitle();
    data[row][1] = book.getAuthor();
    data[row][2] = book.getIsbn();
    data[row][3] = book.getDate();
    data[row][4] = book.getKind();
    data[row][5] = "";
    row++;
}
```

Though it's highly recommended to redesign your classes and remove duplicated/ unnecessary code.

Comment: This cannot be done with existing class design.  But your methods to read the input file can differ the two types of books, so it should be ok to read the same file twice.

Comment: If my answer resolved your initial question, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted.  If you have any additional questions on your task, you can always post a new request at StackOverflow :)

Comment: your answer give me two extra rows..in my file i have two teams of data but jtable appear 4 rows...can you help me?

Comment: Please add your input file to the question

Comment: And by the way, my code is NOT giving extra rows - if there are any duplicated values, they are contained in the lists read in your `XxxBook` classes.  And indeed, your code reading the file has a bunch of bugs and it is able to generate 5 entries while 3 are expected.